# Dataframe to nested dictionary with object as final key value

Tags: dataframe, dictionary, nested, setdefault

I am trying to create a nested dictionary from a pandas dataframe and having some trouble so would appreciate your help.

In essence, I have the below 6 columns - postcode, dwelling_type, bedrooms, year, month and rent

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k3RDZ.png)

I would like to structure the dictionary as follows

{postcode: {(dwelling_type, bedroom): {(year, month, rent)}}}

My code is as follows:

```
d = (df.groupby('postcode')
     .apply(lambda a: dict(a.groupby(['dwelling_type','bedrooms'])
                           .apply(lambda x: dict(x.groupby('year')
                                                 .apply(lambda y: dict(zip(y['month'],y['weekly_rent']))
                                                ))))))
```

The issue I'm having is - I don't know how to group year, month and rent as a single object which corresponds to a (dwelling_type, bedroom) key

Furthermore, my code only seems to be pulling a single rent item - but each month within a year can have hundreds of rents. Need a way for them to all be captured within the object.

By doing this, I will be able to pull the time series (year, month, rents) for any property specification within a postcode with a single unique identifier.

Would also appreciate any insights on how to get this dictionary passed into Google Firebase (if anyone has experience with that)

Many thanks in advance, and sincerest apologies if the above is not clear (I am fairly new to coding).

Comment: Please don't post pictures of your code. format it accordingly using triple backticks ```. The same goes for your dataframe.

Comment: Apologies - I am new to this - I have done this now